# Rescue mdadm RAID 6 array after three disk events

Tags: raid, mdadm

mdadm 3.2.5, 14 disk RAID 6

Had a drive failure Friday.  Two more today in rapid succession.  All drives seem fully operational.

This is roughly 40TB array, I could use your help please to rescue the array.

All members are on partition 2 of each physical disk.

```
# mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: /dev/md/media:0 assembled from 11 drives - not enough to start the array.
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

```
# mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop0
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdo1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdo
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdm1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdm
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdn1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdn
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdj1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdj
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdk1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdk
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdl1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdl
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdi1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdi
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdh1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdh
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdf1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdf
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdd1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdd
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdg1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdg
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sde1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sde
mdadm: /dev/sdm2 is identified as a member of /dev/md/media:0, slot 3.
mdadm: /dev/sdn2 is identified as a member of /dev/md/media:0, slot 8.
mdadm: /dev/sdj2 is identified as a member of /dev/md/media:0, slot 5.
mdadm: /dev/sdk2 is identified as a member of /dev/md/media:0, slot 11.
mdadm: /dev/sdl2 is identified as a member of /dev/md/media:0, slot 4.
mdadm: /dev/sdi2 is identified as a member of /dev/md/media:0, slot 7.
mdadm: /dev/sdh2 is identified as a member of /dev/md/media:0, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sdb2 is identified as a member of /dev/md/media:0, slot 6.
mdadm: /dev/sda2 is identified as a member of /dev/md/media:0, slot 13.
mdadm: /dev/sdf2 is identified as a member of /dev/md/media:0, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/sdd2 is identified as a member of /dev/md/media:0, slot 9.
mdadm: /dev/sdc2 is identified as a member of /dev/md/media:0, slot 6.
mdadm: /dev/sdg2 is identified as a member of /dev/md/media:0, slot 12.
mdadm: /dev/sde2 is identified as a member of /dev/md/media:0, slot 0.
mdadm: added /dev/sdh2 to /dev/md/media:0 as 1
mdadm: added /dev/sdf2 to /dev/md/media:0 as 2
mdadm: added /dev/sdm2 to /dev/md/media:0 as 3
mdadm: added /dev/sdl2 to /dev/md/media:0 as 4
mdadm: added /dev/sdj2 to /dev/md/media:0 as 5
mdadm: added /dev/sdc2 to /dev/md/media:0 as 6 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdi2 to /dev/md/media:0 as 7
mdadm: added /dev/sdn2 to /dev/md/media:0 as 8
mdadm: added /dev/sdd2 to /dev/md/media:0 as 9 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 10 of /dev/md/media:0
mdadm: added /dev/sdk2 to /dev/md/media:0 as 11
mdadm: added /dev/sdg2 to /dev/md/media:0 as 12
mdadm: added /dev/sda2 to /dev/md/media:0 as 13
mdadm: added /dev/sde2 to /dev/md/media:0 as 0
mdadm: /dev/md/media:0 assembled from 11 drives - not enough to start the array.
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

```
# mdadm --examine /dev/sd?2 --verbose
/dev/sda2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : b1c40379:914e5d18:dddb893b:4dc5a28f
           Name : media:0
  Creation Time : Wed Nov  7 22:06:02 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 14

 Avail Dev Size : 5860265984 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 35160446976 (33531.62 GiB 36004.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5860074496 (2794.30 GiB 3000.36 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 822fd02b:454da94c:57f68535:964996b1

    Update Time : Mon Apr  6 19:19:53 2015
       Checksum : 8e7a48ab - correct
         Events : 2384973

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 13
   Array State : AAAAAA.AA..AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdb2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x2
     Array UUID : b1c40379:914e5d18:dddb893b:4dc5a28f
           Name : media:0
  Creation Time : Wed Nov  7 22:06:02 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 14

 Avail Dev Size : 5860265984 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 35160446976 (33531.62 GiB 36004.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5860074496 (2794.30 GiB 3000.36 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
Recovery Offset : 0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 5c4a1046:c232402c:45f1c604:569f6896

    Update Time : Mon Apr  6 16:12:05 2015
       Checksum : 3c7663c2 - correct
         Events : 2382358

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 6
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAA.AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdc2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x2
     Array UUID : b1c40379:914e5d18:dddb893b:4dc5a28f
           Name : media:0
  Creation Time : Wed Nov  7 22:06:02 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 14

 Avail Dev Size : 5860265984 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 35160446976 (33531.62 GiB 36004.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5860074496 (2794.30 GiB 3000.36 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
Recovery Offset : 0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : e211f88d:5c355522:fbeb7134:16b17684

    Update Time : Mon Apr  6 16:28:09 2015
       Checksum : 982c3e96 - correct
         Events : 2382480

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 6
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAA.AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdd2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : b1c40379:914e5d18:dddb893b:4dc5a28f
           Name : media:0
  Creation Time : Wed Nov  7 22:06:02 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 14

 Avail Dev Size : 5860265984 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 35160446976 (33531.62 GiB 36004.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5860074496 (2794.30 GiB 3000.36 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : de3f41b8:3016870c:344f2a92:c08e1085

    Update Time : Mon Apr  6 19:19:34 2015
       Checksum : af2bfdb - correct
         Events : 2384965

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 9
   Array State : AAAAAA.AAA.AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sde2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : b1c40379:914e5d18:dddb893b:4dc5a28f
           Name : media:0
  Creation Time : Wed Nov  7 22:06:02 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 14

 Avail Dev Size : 5860265984 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 35160446976 (33531.62 GiB 36004.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5860074496 (2794.30 GiB 3000.36 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 071afb12:f78f4f15:f65aa629:8eadcfa7

    Update Time : Mon Apr  6 19:19:53 2015
       Checksum : 28a53e70 - correct
         Events : 2384973

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAAAA.AA..AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdf2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : b1c40379:914e5d18:dddb893b:4dc5a28f
           Name : media:0
  Creation Time : Wed Nov  7 22:06:02 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 14

 Avail Dev Size : 5860265984 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 35160446976 (33531.62 GiB 36004.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5860074496 (2794.30 GiB 3000.36 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : e319bdaa:22bc1153:c43b4878:8a9c1832

    Update Time : Mon Apr  6 19:19:53 2015
       Checksum : d7143a42 - correct
         Events : 2384973

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAAAAA.AA..AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdg2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : b1c40379:914e5d18:dddb893b:4dc5a28f
           Name : media:0
  Creation Time : Wed Nov  7 22:06:02 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 14

 Avail Dev Size : 5860265984 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 35160446976 (33531.62 GiB 36004.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5860074496 (2794.30 GiB 3000.36 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : f5477580:94357948:6e97fe82:c8805bcd

    Update Time : Mon Apr  6 19:19:53 2015
       Checksum : 482d21b8 - correct
         Events : 2384973

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 12
   Array State : AAAAAA.AA..AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdh2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : b1c40379:914e5d18:dddb893b:4dc5a28f
           Name : media:0
  Creation Time : Wed Nov  7 22:06:02 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 14

 Avail Dev Size : 5860265984 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 35160446976 (33531.62 GiB 36004.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5860074496 (2794.30 GiB 3000.36 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 3dd1df1b:203c6453:0964ebad:245b1670

    Update Time : Mon Apr  6 19:19:53 2015
       Checksum : bc2a587a - correct
         Events : 2384973

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAAAAA.AA..AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdi2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : b1c40379:914e5d18:dddb893b:4dc5a28f
           Name : media:0
  Creation Time : Wed Nov  7 22:06:02 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 14

 Avail Dev Size : 5860265984 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 35160446976 (33531.62 GiB 36004.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5860074496 (2794.30 GiB 3000.36 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 4a013330:37c565f9:cb761d35:7ce4ddb4

    Update Time : Mon Apr  6 19:19:53 2015
       Checksum : 4278adbb - correct
         Events : 2384973

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 7
   Array State : AAAAAA.AA..AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdj2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : b1c40379:914e5d18:dddb893b:4dc5a28f
           Name : media:0
  Creation Time : Wed Nov  7 22:06:02 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 14

 Avail Dev Size : 5860265984 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 35160446976 (33531.62 GiB 36004.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5860074496 (2794.30 GiB 3000.36 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : d5521994:6c4f04f9:f7ca0dd9:dff3c6cd

    Update Time : Mon Apr  6 19:19:53 2015
       Checksum : 62d6ed06 - correct
         Events : 2384973

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 5
   Array State : AAAAAA.AA..AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdk2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : b1c40379:914e5d18:dddb893b:4dc5a28f
           Name : media:0
  Creation Time : Wed Nov  7 22:06:02 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 14

 Avail Dev Size : 5860265984 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 35160446976 (33531.62 GiB 36004.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5860074496 (2794.30 GiB 3000.36 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : c1514b9f:24616fed:324a50fb:9469043a

    Update Time : Mon Apr  6 19:19:53 2015
       Checksum : f0f3f2a5 - correct
         Events : 2384973

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 11
   Array State : AAAAAA.AA..AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdl2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : b1c40379:914e5d18:dddb893b:4dc5a28f
           Name : media:0
  Creation Time : Wed Nov  7 22:06:02 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 14

 Avail Dev Size : 5860265984 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 35160446976 (33531.62 GiB 36004.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5860074496 (2794.30 GiB 3000.36 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 6c33c472:af1ffd8f:22d10ea3:9edc75bb

    Update Time : Mon Apr  6 19:19:53 2015
       Checksum : 902a8ccd - correct
         Events : 2384973

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 4
   Array State : AAAAAA.AA..AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdm2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : b1c40379:914e5d18:dddb893b:4dc5a28f
           Name : media:0
  Creation Time : Wed Nov  7 22:06:02 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 14

 Avail Dev Size : 5860265984 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 35160446976 (33531.62 GiB 36004.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5860074496 (2794.30 GiB 3000.36 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : b750b4e4:2b1bac5f:cbd3bde5:eab657e7

    Update Time : Mon Apr  6 19:19:53 2015
       Checksum : 405a828f - correct
         Events : 2384973

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AAAAAA.AA..AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdn2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : b1c40379:914e5d18:dddb893b:4dc5a28f
           Name : media:0
  Creation Time : Wed Nov  7 22:06:02 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 14

 Avail Dev Size : 5860265984 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 35160446976 (33531.62 GiB 36004.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5860074496 (2794.30 GiB 3000.36 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 4670b36c:07cbe661:20e3d314:f7c3fd42

    Update Time : Mon Apr  6 19:19:53 2015
       Checksum : 55506e59 - correct
         Events : 2384973

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 8
   Array State : AAAAAA.AA..AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

Comment: There are _two_ devices listed as "Active device 6" and no "Active device 10" at all. This corruption most likely occurred due to an attempt to recover that had been given a wrong device as an argument. It's very unlikely you will ever recover anything from this array, and it's time to go to your backups.

Comment: I recovered the array.  I was previously using a Debian rescue ISO usb stick, and when appending --force it wouldn't assemble the array.  However, in order to capture the debug output I needed a real root filesystem and scp/ssh tools, so I booted from a Debian Live ISO to post the above info --- and later tried --force, which worked this time.

Comment: Well, it's good to hear you got the array assembled. Now you have the more daunting task of figuring out which files were corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Using mdadm --assemble --scan --force did not work (not enough disks, it complained) when using a Debian rescue ISO.  I later tried a Debian Live image (latest build) and the same command was able to recover the array.